# Visual studio Cordova - Could not find gradle wrapper within Android SDK. Might need to update your Android SDK

Tags: android, visual-studio, cordova

I have a cordova project in visual studio. When running the app onto a device the error

> Could not find gradle wrapper within Android SDK. Might need to update your Android SDK

keeps popping up. I have android studio, android sdk(updated) installed. The adb is working and detecting my device all fine. I have searched a lot and most of the answers that i have found are telling to download the sdk once more. But i already have it on my machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visual studio is looking for the gradle wrapper in the location

**path-to-sdk\tools**

folder. So what i did is copied the template folder from

**C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\plugins\android\lib**

and pasted that folder into the above **sdk tools folder**. Re-ran the project. Fixed it.